# Sonar produces a warning that eclipse can't solve with formatter

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

I receive a sonar warning because it is not pleased with this syntax:

```
new Thread() {

                /**
                 * {@inheritDoc}
                 */
                @Override
                public void run() {
                }

            }.start();
```

More specifically, it asks for a white space after any '}' (and there is none before `.start()`). How can I set this in eclipse ?

I have tried going to Window -> Perferences -> Formatter -> Edit -> White Space but I see no option that would add a whitespace before .start.

Answer (score 2):

You can just disable this rule in Sonar, it is pretty much useless.

Go to "Settings -> Quality Profiles" for that purpose.